# Can`t retrieve address and phone number for Intents from ListView item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, arraylist

I'm a beginner android developer, and Im working on an app for my Udacity course. I placed two buttons in the ListView item - one to open a map, and the other one to make a call. To make them work Im trying to retrieve address and phone number from the current object on the list but it`s not working, even though the map and phone app get opened, it just shows my location instead of the object location and a random phone number.

This is the code from my Adapdter class:

```
public class LocationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Location>{
private String address;
//create custom constructor for LocationAdapter
public LocationAdapter (Activity context, ArrayList<Location> locations){
    super (context, 0, locations);
}
//Provide a View (ListView) for adapter
//@param position - the position of the item in the adapter
//@param convertView - the old view to reuse, if available
//@param parent - the parent view this view will be attached to

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView==null){
        listItemView = 
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
//Get Location object from this position on the list
    final Location currentLocation = getItem(position);

    //Set onClickListener on Map Button and use an Intent in onClick method 
to open location on map

    final ImageButton mapButton = (ImageButton) 
listItemView.findViewById(R.id.map_button);
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String address 
 =Integer.toString(currentLocation.getLocationAddressString());
            Intent openMap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            openMap.setData(Uri.parse("geo:"+ address));
            getContext().startActivity(openMap);

        }
    });
     //Set onClickListener on Call Button and use an Intent in onClick method 
to open a dialer
    final ImageButton callButton = (ImageButton) 
listItemView.findViewById(R.id.call_button);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String number 
=Integer.toString(currentLocation.getLocationPhoneNumberString());
            Intent makeCall = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            makeCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
            getContext().startActivity(makeCall);
        }
    });


    //Find ImageView and set an Image of the current Location object
    ImageView locationImage =(ImageView) 
listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    locationImage.setImageResource(currentLocation.getImageResourceId());

    //Find Location Name TextView and set Name of the current Location object
    TextView locationName =(TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    locationName.setText(currentLocation.getLocationNameString());

    //Find Location Description TextView and set Description of the current 
Location object
    TextView locationDescription = (TextView) 
listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    
locationDescription.setText(currentLocation.getLocationDescriptionString());

    return listItemView;
}
 }
```

This is the Location class code:

```
public class Location {
//Image associated with Location
private int mImageResourceId;
//Location name
private int mLocationNameResourceId;
//Location description
private int mLocationDescriptionResourceId;
//Location coordinates
private int mLocationAddressResourceId;
//Location phone number
private int mLocationPhoneNumberResourceId;

//Create a constructor for the Location Object
public Location (int ImageResourceId, int LocationNameResourceId, int 
LocationDescriptionResourceId,
                 int LocationAddressResourceId, int 
LocationPhoneNumberResourceId) {
    mImageResourceId=ImageResourceId;
    mLocationNameResourceId=LocationNameResourceId;
    mLocationDescriptionResourceId=LocationDescriptionResourceId;
    mLocationAddressResourceId=LocationAddressResourceId;
    mLocationPhoneNumberResourceId=LocationPhoneNumberResourceId;
  }
  //Get image resource id
public int getImageResourceId(){
    return mImageResourceId;
  }
//get Location name
public int getLocationNameString(){
    return mLocationNameResourceId;
}
//get Location description
public int getLocationDescriptionString(){
    return mLocationDescriptionResourceId;
}
//get Location address
public int getLocationAddressString(){
    return mLocationAddressResourceId;
}
//get Location phone number
public int getLocationPhoneNumberString(){
    return mLocationPhoneNumberResourceId;
}
}
```

---

#### Solved

So, the issue turned out to be in storing LocationAddress as Integer in custom class, instead of storing it as a String.

Answer (score 1):

Think this might be related to how the address URI is created on this line:

```
openMap.setData(Uri.parse("geo:"+ address));
```

Basically, this is going to output an addressUri that looks something like:

```
geo:123 Sesame St
```

But looking at the examples at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents requires a couple changes:

1) That latitude/longitude should be set to 0,0 when using an address
2) You'll actually have to specify the `?q=` part of the Uri

So I think if you change the previously mentioned line to this, it should work:

```
openMap.setData(Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+ address));
```

Comment: Hi guys,  Ive tried to make the changes you suggested, but it is still not working.